# How to write UTF-8 encoded values in SQL Server using OLEDB connection string?

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am trying to insert a character 'Č', I found this character is UTF-8 encoded.
when I insert this character into a SQL Server table, it stores the data as plain 'C'.

I am using OLEDB connection to insert the data, I have tried to use charset attribute in connection string but no luck.

However I am able to read this character from the SQL Server table in correct format, but issue is arises while insertion and update.

Is there any way to insert these kind of characters into SQL Server using OLEDB connection string?

Comment: SQL Server (up to version 2016) doesn't support UTF-8 - it has Unicode character sets - but those are always UCS-2 (UTF-16). To use these, make sure your column datatype is `NVARCHAR` in the SQL Server table, and if you need to specify a Unicode string literal, always prefix it with an `N` (to indicate Unicode): `DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(10) = N'Čabc'`.

Comment: It's hard to think of a programming environment where you would use OLEDB and UTF-8. UTF-16 seems much, much more likely. So, how are you using OLEDB and UTF-8?

Comment: I was trying to find if I can mention charset and encoding in oledb connection string, but there is no way to add those properties

Comment: In many programming environments, character set and encoding are intrinsic to the text datatypes (e.g., string and char) and the object methods take that into account transparently if needed. For example, in VB (since VB4) String is the UTF-16 encoding (or its precursor, UCS-2) of Unicode as it is in C#, Java, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: Yes, after making datatype nvarchar and insert query  by prepending value by n'value' works fine, but in my work environment I can not change the destination data type, at present it's nchar.

Comment: Your database schema doesn't support Unicode text. Helicopters can't fly upside down. So, either stop there, change the schema or hack it (break the contract that the current schema declares and/or other undeclared agreements with the readers and writers).